# React and express

Tags: javascript, json, express, reactjs

These are the contents of the index.html file

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "app">
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx">


    </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the contents of my app.jsx file is

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello React!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

The contents of server.js file is

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('Express server is up on port 3000');
});
```

And the contents of package.json is

```
 {
  "name": "hello-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple react app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "varun",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

The directory structure is 
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjYa8.png)

When I run the file using the command node server.js, the page localhost://3000 turns out to be blank. I was expecting **Hello React!** to appear on screen. 
I am starting out with react and express and I couldn't figure out why this is so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your `index.html` file from your `express server`. Add the following to your `server.js` code by settign the correct path to index.html file relative to your current file and you should be able to see your result

```
 app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send('/path/to/index.html');
});
```

Comment: What is your directory structure can you post that

Comment: Directory structure is there towards the bottom of the question

Comment: Figured it out. There was a typo. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this instead:

```
res.sendFile('public/index.html' , { root : __dirname});
```

This worked for me. the root:__dirname will take the address where server.js is in the above example and then to get to the index.html ( in this case) the returned path is to get to the directory where public folder is

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There was a **typo** where I imported **Babel, react and React-Dom**.

**Corrected code**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>**
```

Missed out on **'.com'** for all the three libraries. Found out by inspecting the page(Libraries weren't getting loaded).